# Tensorflow: How can I extract image features from a specific layer of a pre-trained CNN?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have a pre-trained CNN model as a .pb file. I can load the model and extract the final vector from the last layer for all images. Now I would like to extract the vector coming from a specific layer and not the final for my images. I am using an import_graph_def function to load the model and I don't know the names of the layers because **.pb** file is large and I can't open it.

How can I run one part of the model and not the whole in order to get vectors until the layer I want?

Comment: One thing you could try is to use tf.Graph.get_operations() to get a list of the nodes (operations) in the graph. You can then, say, print the node names and search for the one you want.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am using an import_graph_def function which returns the tensor that I need. When I print that tensor I get: Tensor("pool_3/_reshape:0", shape=(1, 2048), dtype=float32). Now I want to get for example bottleneck_tensor with name "pool_3:0" and shape=(1, 8, 8, 2048). How should I return the tensor?

Comment: Problem solved thanks to Steven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach other than what was mentioned by Peter Hawkins, to use tf.Graph.get_operations() in the comments is to use tensorboard to find the name of the layer you would like to extract from.

From there you can just use

```
graph.get_tensor_by_name("import/layer_name")
```

to extract out whichever features you want.

Comment: I am not using tensorboard yet but thank you very much!

Comment: Oh man you saved me. I thought I have to use tensorboard, but running only the command you mentioned I can get whichever tensor I want. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Please mark as solved if it's done.  Also I only mentioned tensorboard because you mentioned you didn't know the names of the layers which is kind of necessary to be able to get the tensors. Glad it worked!

Comment: But how know the names of the layers?

Comment: @hafiz031 you can use: sess.graph.get_operations()